# In my hybrid project i can not create a viewbag

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I had a classical web forms application. I wanted to be add mvc 4 in it.

For this manner i added necessary references. 
i made some changes in web.config

and i created two folders named Views and Controllers. And then i added a view in Views folder. The code like this

```
 @{
 ViewBag.Title = "About";
}

<ul>
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
</ul>
```

but i m having errors al the time.

The name ViewBag does not exist in current context.

what can be problem.

Comment: By the looks of it you are still missing a reference

Comment: which reference should i add? @JanR

Comment: @cerq it seems you have to make chanje in your web.config file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have missed some Web.config  int the view folder **/Views/Web.Config**

```
 <configuration>

 <system.web.webPages.razor>
<host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />

  <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage"> // <-- this line and contents are important
    <namespaces>
      <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
      <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
      <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
      <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
    </namespaces>
  </pages>
```

try this and let me know

Comment: i can build my solution but still i m having red underline on ViewBag is it normal?

Comment: @cerq whether you can build now or not ?

Comment: @cerq im sure it will work well .. and even you can google it and check

Comment: thans a lot it is working but still viewbag marked as wrong. is it normal? because when i tried to run my About.cshtml like ..../Home/About it is not routing. probably there is another problem but maybe it is relevant?

Comment: @cerq No . you can try to change the routing file .. you can redirect

Comment: what does changin routing file mean. redirecting? how? please help me

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33697/discussion-between-backtrack-and-cerq)